# Return value if not exist

Tags: django

Within my template, I have a number of values being presented from data within the database.

`{{ fundamentals.project_category }}`

But when no data exists it throws an error
`matching query does not exist.` i think because the no data is being returned in the query set within the `fundamentals` model.
`fundamentals = project.fundamentals_set.get()`

within my view im trying:

```
    if project.fundamentals_set.get().exists():
        fundamentals = project.fundamentals_set.get()
    else:
        #what should i put here?
```

Im assuming an `if` statment is requried along with `exists():` but this isn't working and im not sure what i should put in the `else` statement to return something like `nothing exists` when no data exists within the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `exists()` on a queryset. Your call to `get()` in your condition is executing a query which you don't want if there could be no results.

```
if project.fundamentals_set.all().exists():
    fundamentals = project.fundamentals_set.get()
else:
    # what should i put here?
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, Iain. I was almost there.  nice one